# Creating a dynamic char array

Tags: c, file, char, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to read in the a file and store the words into a dynamic char array. Right now I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

I have tried using strdup() and strcpy() still i am getting the same error

```
char ** array;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int size = 0;
    int i;
    FILE * file;
    char * line;
    size_t len;
    ssize_t read;


    file = fopen("wordsEn.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL){
            printf("Error coudl not open wordsEn.txt\n");
            return -1;
    }

    while((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1){
            size++;
    }

    array = (char **) malloc((sizeof(char *) * size));
    rewind(file);

    i = 0;
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1){
            //strcpy(array[i], line);
            array[i] = strdup(line);
            i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
            printf("%s", array[i]);
    }
}
```

I am expecting for example array[0] to return the string 'alphabet'

Comment: *store the words into a dynamic char array* – What does that mean? `array[0]` is the first word, `array[1]` the 2nd, `array[2]` the 3rd, ... ?

Comment: @Swordfish Yes, array[0] is the first word.

Comment: be aware that this `getline()` isn't standard C.

Comment: I put a full corrected version of your code if you are interrested

Comment: `line` is uninitialised before its address is passed to `getline()`.   The POSIX `getline()` function dereferences the address it receives and uses the value to decide how to behave (if the value is `NULL` it calls `malloc()`, if the value is not `NULL` it is ASSUMED to be a buffer returned by `malloc()`).   Since `line` is uninitialised in `main()` this causes `getline()` to have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

warning to get a newly allocated line through *getline* each time you have to reset *line* to NULL and *len* to 0 each time, for instance :

```
while(line = NULL, len = 0, (read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1){
```

Note you do not have to read two times the file, you can use *malloc* then *realloc* to increase the size of the (really) dynamic array

---

A Proposal :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char ** array = malloc(0);
  size_t size = 0;
  FILE * file;
  char * line;
  size_t len;
  ssize_t read;

  file = fopen("wordsEn.txt", "r");
  if(file == NULL) {
    printf("Error coudl not open wordsEn.txt\n");
    return -1;
  }

  while (line = NULL, len = 0, (read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1){
    array = realloc(array, (size+1) * sizeof(char *));
    array[size++] = line;
  }
  free(line); /* do not forget to free it */
  fclose(file);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
    printf("%s", array[i]);
  }

  /* free resources */
  for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
    free(array[i]);
  }
  free(array);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall ar.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat wordsEn.txt 
turlututu foo
bar
loop
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
turlututu foo
bar
loop
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under valgrind :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==13161== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13161== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13161== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13161== Command: ./a.out
==13161== 
turlututu foo
bar
loop
==13161== 
==13161== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13161==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13161==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 5,976 bytes allocated
==13161== 
==13161== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13161== 
==13161== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13161== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: @xing this is exactely what I am thinking about ;-)

Comment: @xing yes the first time I read wrongly _fgets_ rather than _getline_ in my head, I edited my answer

Comment: @xing this what I did, I edited my answer to put a full version